# How to use one react app into another react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react apps, parent app and child app. and child app have an hash router.

1. I have build the child app using npm run build, It creates build folder.
2. That build folder moved into inside the public folder in parent App.
3. In Parent App, I have a menu name "testing", when we navigate this menu, wants to render a child App content. to this I have used iframe inside testing component, src mapped to required router
   like this

```js
const Testing = () => {

    return (
        <div className="testing" style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
            <iframe
                title="testing"
                id={"chartID"}
                className="iframe"
                src={`${AppSettings.publicUrl}/tradjini/index.html#/margin-calculator`}
                /// src="http://localhost:3001/app/strategies"
                height="100%"
                width="100%"
                frameBorder="0"
                name="testingView"
            >
            </iframe>
        </div>
        
    );
};

export default Testing;
```

with this we can able achieve the task, **but need to use child app content without using iframes** any solution are most welcome.

In react doc I could see https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project is this helpful for my task?
**The task wants to use one react app menus into another react app without calling external links in iframe**

Answer (score 0):

Why are the two applications separated?
Unless there is a specific reason to separate them then the solution would be to:

1. Move your Child Application into a component.
2. Render that component into your parent app using the same return statement that renders an iframe.

Child APP:

```
const ChildApplication = () => {

return ( %%%Child App React Code%%% )

}

export default ChildApplication
```

Parent App:

```
%%%% Testing Code %%%%
return ( <ChildApplication /> )
```

Comment: Child Application is the common one, this child app build folder we want to reuse in many applications.

Comment: The above solution will not work, since i want to use child app build folder in parent app, without using iframe

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve your objective using [Micro frontend](https://micro-frontends.org/). There are some frameworks that allows you to create your page using multiple React projects or even other frameworks like Vue, Angular etc.

If your only objective is testing, with [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) you can test your components, see them working and even create a nice documentation with it.